# What is the difference between Luong attention and Bahdanau attention?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, attention-model

These two attentions are used in **seq2seq** modules. The two different attentions are introduced as multiplicative and additive attentions in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_guides/python/contrib.seq2seq) TensorFlow documentation. What is the difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are very well explained in [a PyTorch seq2seq tutorial](https://github.com/spro/practical-pytorch/blob/master/seq2seq-translation/seq2seq-translation.ipynb).

The main difference is how to score similarities between the current decoder input and encoder outputs.

Comment: is it like global and local attention?

Comment: I went through the pytorch seq2seq tutorial. So it's only the score function that different in the Luong attention. Otherwise both attentions are soft attentions. Am I correct?

Answer (score 39):

I went through this [Effective Approaches to Attention-based Neural Machine Translation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04025.pdf). In the section *3.1* They have mentioned the difference between two attentions as follows,

1. **Luong attention** used top hidden layer states in both of encoder and decoder. *But **Bahdanau attention** take concatenation of forward and backward source hidden state (Top Hidden Layer)*.
2. In **Luong attention** they get the decoder hidden state at time ***t***. Then calculate attention scores and from that get the context vector which will be concatenated with hidden state of the decoder and then predict.

   But in the **Bahdanau** at time ***t*** we consider about ***t-1*** hidden state of the decoder. Then we calculate alignment , context vectors as above. But then we concatenate this context with hidden state of the decoder at ***t-1***. So before the softmax this concatenated vector goes inside a GRU.
3. Luong has diffferent types of alignments. **Bahdanau** has only concat score alignment model.

[image: Alignment methdods]

Comment: Yes, but what Wa stands for? Is it a shift scalar, weight matrix or something else?

Comment: @Zimeo the first one dot, measures the similarity directly using dot product.
The Wa matrix in the "general"  equations can be thought of as some sort of weighted similarity or a more general notion of similarity where setting Wa to the diagonal matrix gives you the dot similarity

Comment: The way I see it, the second form 'general' is an extension of the dot product idea. When we set W_a to the identity matrix both forms coincide. One way of looking at Luong's form is to do a linear transformation on the hidden units and then taking their dot products. This is exactly how we would implement it in code. The Bandanau variant uses a concatenative (or additive) instead of the dot product/multiplicative forms.

Answer (score 12):

I just wanted to add a picture for a better understanding to the @shamane-siriwardhana

[image]

the main difference is in the output of the decoder network

Answer (score 5):

There are actually many differences besides the scoring and the local/global attention. A brief summary of the differences:

1. Bahdanau et al use an extra function to derive hs_{t-1} from hs_t. I didn't see a good reason anywhere on why they do this but a paper by Pascanu et al throws a clue..maybe they are looking to make the RNN deeper. Luong of course uses the hs_t directly
2. Bahdanau recommend uni-directional encoder and bi-directional decoder. Luong has both as uni-directional. Luong also recommends taking just the top layer outputs; in general, their model is simpler
3. The more famous one - There is no dot product of hs_{t-1} (the decoder output) with encoder states in Bahdanau's. Instead they use separate weights for both and do an addition instead of a multiplication. This perplexed me for a long while as multiplication is more intuitive, until I read somewhere that addition is less resource intensive...so there are tradeoffs
4. in Bahdanau, we have a choice to use more than one unit to determine w and  u - the weights that are applied individually on the decoder hidden state at t-1 and the encoder hidden states. Having done that, we need to massage the tensor shape back & hence, there is a need for a multiplication with another weight v. Determining v is a simple linear transformation and needs just 1 unit
5. Luong gives us local attention in addition to global attention. Local attention is a combination of soft and hard attention
6. Luong gives us many other ways to calculate the attention weights..most involving a dot product..hence the name multiplcative. I think there were 4 such equations. We can pick and choose the one we want
7. There are some minor changes like Luong concatenates the context and the decoder hidden state and uses one weight instead of 2 separate ones
8. Last and the most important one is that Luong feeds the attentional vector to the next time-step as they believe that past attention weight history is important and helps predict better values

The good news is that most are superficial changes. Attention as a concept is so powerful that any basic implementation suffices. There are 2 things that seem to matter though - the passing of attentional vectors to the next time step and the concept of local attention(esp if resources are constrained). The rest dont influence the output in a big way.

For more specific details, please refer https://towardsdatascience.com/create-your-own-custom-attention-layer-understand-all-flavours-2201b5e8be9e

Answer (score 4):

[Luong-style attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Attention?version=nightly):    scores = tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b=True)

[Bahdanau-style attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/AdditiveAttention): scores = tf.reduce_sum(tf.tanh(query + value), axis=-1)